# Travelling within and outside of Schengen with Italian Ricevuta + biometric passport (visa free)

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, italy, visa-free-entry, ukraine

I am a Ukrainian citizen who is studying in Italy. Several weeks ago I have applied for renewal of my permesso di soggiorno, so at the moment I have expired permesso di soggiorno and new ricevuta di soggiorno. I also have a biometric passport which allows to travel within Schengen zone for 90 days (since 2017 there is a visa-free regime between Ukraine and the countries of Schengen Zone)). Therefore I'd like to know am I able to travel within Schengen zone with ricevuta and biometric passport  (I suppose yes, but I haven't found any official document where it is written extensively. Also, I know that if you're holding a temporary residence permit issued by Germany/Slovakia you can travel within Schengen zone with a biometric passport). I'd also like to know am I able to leave and re-enter to Schengen zone through other Schengen countries with those documents.

Answer (score 1):

No, the receipt is not a valid travel document. You must wait for a new plastic anti-counterfeit residence permit card to travel to other countries, or use the rest of the 90 Schengen days. In the latter case, **make sure you have an entry stamp on your passport**.

The receipt can be used only to enter Italy from Ukraine, not to travel to other Schengen countries.

I said about the entry stamp because you won't get a stamp by entering Italy with the residence permit, but the gate agent at the airport will thoroughly check your passport for stamps.